# How to obtain and work with steady-state part of DE solution?

Tags: maple

I'm trying to obtain ***resonance curves*** of the system. System can be described as

```
F,m,k:=2,1,4: 
lambda:= beta/(2*m): 
omega:=sqrt(k/m):
de:=diff(x(t),t$2)+2*lambda*diff(x(t),t)+omega^2*x(t)=F*cos(gamma1*t):
cond:=x(0)=0, D(x)(0)=0:
sol := dsolve({cond, de});
```

Solving gives sum of terms, some of which "die out" with time (since these terms have `exp(-...*t)`) and some of which form steady-state solution (solution for `t -> ∞`). This solution will be in form  `xstst=f(gamma1)*sin(...)`. In order to obtain ***resonance curves***, I need to plot `f(gamma1)` (for chosen constant `betas`, say, `2,1,0.5,0.25,`etc.).

I've solved this "by hand" and found `f := F/(sqrt((-gamma1^2+omega^2)^2+4*lambda^2*gamma1^2))`. Plotting this for any chosen beta gives the result needed, for example, for `beta:=0.5` the plot is [image]

I wonder if I can obtain these curves using maple functions only (without solving anything "by hand" at all).

[edited][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to expect Maple to represent the result in terms of either `sin(theta)` or `cos(theta)`, using some formulas for those terms that appear nowhere in the problem specification and are entirely introduced by you.

The following is obtained using a radical (square root) in each of `cond1` and `cond2`.

```
restart;
de := diff(x(t),t,t)+2*lambda*diff(x(t),t)+omega^2*x(t)=F*cos(gamma1*t):
cond := x(0)=0, D(x)(0)=0:

sol := dsolve({cond, de}):

E,T := selectremove(hastype,rhs(sol),specfunc(anything,exp)):

lprint(T);

    F*(2*sin(gamma1*t)*gamma1*lambda-cos(gamma1*t)*gamma1^2
    +cos(gamma1*t)*omega^2)/(gamma1^4+4*gamma1^2*lambda^2-
    2*gamma1^2*omega^2+omega^4)

cond1 := cos(theta) = (-gamma1^2+omega^2)
            /((-gamma1^2+omega^2)^2+4*lambda^2*gamma1^2)^(1/2):

cond2 := sin(theta) = (-2*lambda*gamma1)
            /((-gamma1^2+omega^2)^2+4*lambda^2*gamma1^2)^(1/2):

frontend(algsubs, [numer(rhs(cond1))=lhs(cond1)*denom(rhs(cond1)),
                   numer(T)],
         [{`+`,`*`,`=`},{}]):

frontend(algsubs, [numer(rhs(cond2))=lhs(cond2)*denom(rhs(cond2)),
                   %],
         [{`+`,`*`,`=`},{}]):

ans := collect(combine(%, trig),cos)/denom(T):

lprint(ans);

    F*cos(gamma1*t+theta)/(gamma1^4+4*gamma1^2*lambda^2-
    2*gamma1^2*omega^2+omega^4)^(1/2)

subsans := eval(eval(ans,[lambda=beta/(2*m),omega=sqrt(k/m)]),
                [F=2,m=1,k=4]):

lprint(subsans);

    2*cos(gamma1*t+theta)
    /(beta^2*gamma1^2+gamma1^4-8*gamma1^2+16)^(1/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but when I run your code I get some terms with exponentials, some with sines and some with cosines. You can grab the coefficient of the sine terms with

```
coeff( collect( rhs( sol ) , sin( gamma1 * t ) ) , sin( gamma1 * t ) , 1 )
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need to find coeff only for the last summand (which doesn't contain exp(-t*...)) and term will be like f(gamma1)*sin(gamma1*t+theta), where theta is also a function of lambda,omega and gamma1. I've tried to collect this, but it seems that it won't work (collecting gives the same 3rd term as before). At least, now I know that it's impossible. +1 for the help, thank you. This idea was very useful for understanding.

Comment: @KellyShepphard --- I suspect it is possible, but I'm still not 100% sure of exactly what you want. (There is no theta in your code, and I don't know where the sqrt comes from in the work you did by hand.) Perhaps I can give a better answer if you upload a screenshot from Maple and highlight the terms that you want to isolate.

Comment: I've added screenshot. Sorry for the lack of info, I've thought Maple automatically solves it as was needed.